# Rdlc Report is not loading

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, rdlc

I have a common report viewer in Win Form application

And I'm getting DataSource From SP that is coming from EF 5.0; I have a Dataset in xml file. That contains the property from the stored procedure.

My code sample is

```
private void btnNewStaff_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SaleManager aManager = new SaleManager();
        var reportForm = new CommonReportViewer(); 
        reportForm.commonRptViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "RptTransactionDetails.rdlc";
        var data = aManager.GetTransactionDetails(-9223372036854775808);
        var reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource("TransactionDetails", data);

        reportForm.ShowReport(new[] { reportDataSource });
    }
```

where -9223372036854775808 is transaction ID (it will dynamic later) and `TransactionDetails` inside the datasource is the name of Dataset in RDLC.

From ShowReport it is going to the common report form And that is

```
internal void ShowReport(IEnumerable<ReportDataSource> dataSources)
{
    foreach (var dataSource in dataSources)
        commonRptViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dataSource);

    commonRptViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();
    commonRptViewer.Refresh();
}
```

But there is no report form loading neither the report, can't figure out where the problem is..

Comment: What is the return type for GetTransactionDetails function?

Answer (score 0):

Your report path is not an actual path.
You should either define the report as an **embedded resource** or define the **full report path**.

To use the **embedded report**, use this:

```
reportForm.commonRptViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "RptTransactionDetails.rdlc";
```

To use the **report path**, calculate the path (something like this):

```
 string appPath = Application.StartupPath;
 reportForm.commonRptViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = Path.Combine(appPath, Reports\RptTransactionDetails.rdlc");
```